# How to model dropout and which regression do you use?

Tags: r, regression, logit

I have a large Dataset from a social social like network.
I want to analyze which facotrs motivates them to write another post in the network. Then they would appear again in the data.
Simplified the data looks like this:

```
row.    member_id   entry_id    previous_comment_count  timestamp
1       1            a              0                    2008-06-09 12:41:00
2       1            b              4                    2008-07-14 18:41:00
3       1            c              5                    2008-07-17 15:40:00
4       2            d              0                    2008-06-09 12:41:00
5       2            e              50                   2008-09-18 10:22:00
6       3            f              0                    2008-10-03 13:36:00
```

Each member_id is a individual member. If they don't appear again in the dataset, they dropped out. For the above example member 1 did post 3 entries, the last on 07-17, the member 3 only 1, the last and only one on 10-03.

Let's say I assume that the previous_comments_count is the reason they stay/drop out.

How can I do this ? Do I have to change my data ? And what regression model should I use ? ( I want to do this in R)

My current idea is to add a new column "dropped_out" with 0 if they did not drop out. Then I would create a new row for each member, with the "previous_comment_count" and "dopped_out" = 1. After that I would try a Logit-Regression on "dropped_out". Does this makes sense in a statistical way ;) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have time to event data the usual thing you look at it is survival analysis which is designed for data that are censored. In your case, data are censored because some people don't drop out. There are many methods of survival analysis, but by far the most common is Cox proportional hazards regression. In `R` you can use `coxph` in the `survival` package.

It looks like you have time dependent covariates, but they can be accommodated in `coxph`.